# Jquery input field calculation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to perform simple calculation using Jquery on input fields but cannot make it work.

```
<label for="a"><input type="number" id="a" value="1" size="2" maxlength="1"></label>
<label for="b"><input type="number" id="b" value="1" size="2" maxlength="1"></label>

<div class="button">
<a name="qtybutton" onClick="calculation()">update</a>
</div>

<script>
function calculation() {
    variable = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var total = 0;
    var sqty = $('#a').val();
    var itemprice = $('#b').val();
    var total = sqty * itemprice;

    $('#total').val(total);
    alert("OK");
}
</script>
```

I get alert "OK" so at least I know that jquery function is working, but no calculation is performed. I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Where is your `<input id='total' type='text' />` element? You need an input to set the value of.

Comment: <p id="total">Total:</p> this is it

Comment: Okay, I posted my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.val()` function usually is associated with inputs, whereas the `.html()` function puts text inside of an element. Try this:

```
function calculation() {
    variable = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var total = 0;
    var sqty = $('#a').val();
    var itemprice = $('#b').val();
    var total = sqty * itemprice;

    $('#total').html(total);
    alert("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work when you have an element named `total`:

```
<label for="a"><input type="number" id="a" value="1" size="2" maxlength="1"></label>
<label for="b"><input type="number" id="b" value="1" size="2" maxlength="1"></label>
<label for="total"><input type="number" id="total"  size="2"></label>

<div class="button">
<a name="qtybutton" onClick="calculation()">update</a>
</div>
```

Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/chc2v5qe/